# Как получить и обработать событие с помощью Observer и встроить эту функцию в поток?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, observer

Часть первая:
Как прочитать текстовый файл по событию, которое получаем с помощью Observer.

Пример: В директории 'C:\ForTest' лежит файл text.txt
С помощью нижеуказанного кода, если мы что-то напишем в в файл text.txt и сохраним его, в консоль будет выведен путь к файлу, который изменен.
А как получить текст файла, который был изменен?
Если пробовать открыть файл с помощью полученного пути - он его не видит по какой-то причине.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.txt", "*.jpg"]

    def process(self, event):
        """
        event.event_type
            'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'
        event.is_directory
            True | False
        event.src_path
            path/to/observed/file
        """

        # print(event.src_path, event.event_type)
        out = str(event.src_path)
        print(out)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = 'C:\\ForTest'
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path=args if args else '.')
    
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Часть вторая:
как объединить поток Observer с потоком bot_polling Aiogram так, чтобы текст из файла test.txt, отправлялся в бот

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart

router: Router = Router()

async def start():
    bot: Bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)

    dp: Dispatcher = Dispatcher()

    dp.include_router(router=router)

    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())
```